# biblatex reading style - how to remove entries without an annotation?

Tags: biblatex

Here's a MWE that I thought it would only remove entries without the `annotation` AKA `annote` field.  But actually it removes *all* of the entries.

Here's what the documentation says, on page 78 of the biblatex manual:

> If `notfield` is used then only apply the step if the ⟨*entryfield*⟩ does not exist.
>
> If `entrynull` is set, processing of the `\map` immediately terminates and the current entry is not created. It is as if it did not exist in the datasource. Obviously, you should select the entries which you want to apply this to using prior mapping steps.

By wrapping these into one step I thought I would first test if the annotation field is set, and then, if not, delete the entry.  Is there a way to achieve that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=reading,
            entryhead=true,
            entrykey=false,
            natbib,
            hyperref=false,
            url=false,
            doi=false,
            %style=apa,
            sorting=nyt,
            isbn=false,
            %backref=true,
            firstinits=true,
            minnames=13,
            maxnames=35,
            minbibnames=10,
            maxbibnames=100,
            parentracker=true,
            defernumbers=true,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
     \step[notfield=annotation,entrynull=true]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{ABCDFG,
  annote = {This is a very nice paper.},
  author = {GGPB},
  booktitle = {BOEUS},
  keywords = {clipping},
  title = {NOAP},
  volume = {0},
  year = {2005},
}
@inproceedings{XXXXXX,
  author = {PQR},
  booktitle = {BBC},
  keywords = {LLM},
  title = {ARP},
  year = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug specific to `entrynull` to me. `\step[notfield=annote, fieldset=note, fieldvalue=Note]` works as expected. **Note:** You should use `annote` as is actually in your bib file, not `annotation` as this mapping isn't yet applied at the time your user mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data mapping happens at a very early state when the `annote` field is still called `annote` and not yet `annotation` (the renaming from `annote` to `annotation` also happens in a sourcemap, but that map is executed after user-defined `\DeclareSourcemap`s). So you need `notfield=annote`.

Furthermore, it seems that `entrynull` only works safely if it is used in a `\step` of its own. All examples in the documentation use it like this.

If you think that `\step[notfield=annotation,entrynull=true]` should work (and from the text of the documentation I found no compelling argument that it should not), please open an issue at the Biber bugtracker: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues.

*edit: There was a discussion about this on the Biber bugracker at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/238. As a consequence the `biblatex` documentation has been amended [to emphasise that `notfield` should be used in a `\step` of its own together with `final`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/0339ca14d2a955e267bde070f3432c7683ac7b91).*

To catch entries without `annote` and `annotation` and null them I suggest

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=reading, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
     \step[notfield=annote, final]
     \step[notfield=annotation, final]
     \step[entrynull]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{ABCDFG,
  annote    = {This is a very nice paper.},
  author    = {GGPB},
  booktitle = {BOEUS},
  keywords  = {clipping},
  title     = {NOAP},
  volume    = {0},
  year      = {2005},
}
@inproceedings{XXXXXX,
  author    = {PQR},
  booktitle = {BBC},
  keywords  = {LLM},
  title     = {ARP},
  year      = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Only <code>ABCDFG</code> (with <code>annote</code>) appears in the bibliography, <code>XXXXXX</code> (without <code>annote</code>) is not present]

Comment: The logic is the reverse of what I'm after: entries with empty annotations are preserved as such, and anything that is not empty is nullified.  The behaviour is the same as in my original MWE.

Comment: @JoeCorneli Sorry, I might have misunderstood you. I thought you wanted to see the entry with `annote` (`ABCDFG` in the MWE) and wanted to null everything else (`XXXXXX`). That is what my MWE does - see the added full MWE and picture.

Comment: OK, it works! I think I forgot to run biber.  Sorry for the noise, and thanks for the updated answer!  Apart from that oversight the wording of the manual is a bit confusing: "If `notfield` is used then only apply the step if the ⟨*entryfield*⟩ does not exist."  I would have thought that the first step in the recipe would match any items without an `annote`, then result in `final` which means no further steps executed.